# Как сделать транзакции в Yii2?

Tags: yii2, active-record

Хочу сделать транзакции в Yii2

Нашел такой пример

```
private function applyOperation($model)
{
        //изменяем баланс контрагента
        $contragent= Contragents::find( $model->contragent );   
        $contragent->balance = $contragent->balance + $model->prihod;
        $contragent->balance = $contragent->balance - $model->rashod;            

        //запомним в операции текущий баланс контрагента
        $model->balance=$contragent->balance;            

        //сохраним и модель операции и модель контрагента
        $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
if ($contragent->save() && $model->save()) {
// если сохранение прошло без ошибок, то коммитим транзакцию
$transaction->commit();
return true;
} else {
// если хоть одно из сохранений не удалось, то откатываемся
$transaction->rollback();
return false;
}
}
```

Экшн

```
if ($model->load($_POST) && $this->applyOperation($model) ) {
//return $this->redirect(  куда то там )
}
```

Подскажите как форму вьюхи написать?
Не могу никак понять там одна переменная $contragent, а мне ж надо у одного юзера забрать с баланса, другому добавить.

Comment: Так в чем вопрос то? Как делать транзакции? Или что-то дописать в форме представления?

Comment: Ну вообще транзакции, я их никогда не делал. Этот код нашел в инете, еще не знаю рабочий ли он.

Answer (score 2):

Задача транзакции обеспечить выполнение ряда sql запросов как одну атомарную операцию.

В примере все операции с ActiveRecord и базой данных внутри try блока до коммита будут выполнены в транзакции. В случае ошибки в базу данных не запишется ни одно изменение.

[Пример из документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-transaction.html):

```
$transaction = $connection->beginTransaction();
try {
    $connection->createCommand($sql1)->execute();
    $connection->createCommand($sql2)->execute();
    //.... other SQL executions
    $transaction->commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}
```